# Could not add a line after a certain line in the nginx.conf file on linux

Tags: shell

Add the below line to the nginx.conf file after the **'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';**... line.

**log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user $time_iso8601 [$request_time] "$request" '**

I have tried the below command but I am not able to add.

**sed -i '/'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';/a log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user $time_iso8601 [$request_time] "$request" '' $path/nginx.conf**

Comment: Are you sure about the quoting with `'"'` you show?

Comment: @David C. Rankin 
Sure.

Comment: Okay, the reason I ask is neither the docs or use examples, e.g. [Nginx redirect based on user agent](https://serverfault.com/q/775463/332034) along with [X-Forwarded-For](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/) do not show the use of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comments, and noting the use of double quotes in the `nginx.conf` which I don't find support for, you can accomplish your substitution with `sed` as follows:

```bash
sed -i '/^"\$http_user_agent"[[:space:]]"\$http_x_forwarded_for"/a log_format main $remote_addr - $remote_user $time_iso8601 [$request_time] "$request"' nginx.conf
```

(**note:** in the REGEX, `'$'` has special meaning and must be escaped, e.g. `\$`, or included within `[..]`)

Also note, if you can have whitespace at the beginning of the match-line, then add a *zero or more* space REGEX anchored at the beginning, e.g.

```bash
sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*"\$http_user_agent"[[:space:]]"\$http_x_forwarded_for"/ ...
```

(this will work exactly the same as the first, it simply allows for zero or more spaces at the beginning)

**Example Use/Output**

Beginning with a sample `nginx.conf` file:

```
$ cat nginx.conf
line
line
line
"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"
line
line
```

Applying the `sed` expression above:

```bash
$ sed -i '/^"\$http_user_agent"[[:space:]]"\$http_x_forwarded_for"/a log_format main $remote_addr - $remote_user $time_iso8601 [$request_time] "$request"' nginx.conf
```

results in the file:

```
$ cat nginx.conf
line
line
line
"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"
log_format main $remote_addr - $remote_user $time_iso8601 [$request_time] "$request"
line
line
```